# Why does git clone seem to look in the home folder not ~/repositories

Tags: git, gitolite

I have installed gitolite and can successfully push and pull gitolite-admin. I am having a problem when I add a repo in the conf file. The repo correctly gets created in ~/repositories but when I try and clone it from there I get "fatal:'repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository.

I am cloning using

```
git clone git@myserver:repo.git
```

If I manually create a repo in ~ I seem to be able to clone that with the above syntax so it appears that it is trying to clone from the wrong location.
If I put

```
git clone git@myserver:repositories/repo.git
```

it looks like it can see it but then throws a bunch of hook errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the gitolite wrapper is not being run and you're on bare ssh.

Do you have your ssh key listed multiple times in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`? It should be there only once, put there by gitolite, with `command=".../gl-auth-command..."` wrapping.